# CSS & Button: How to override native CSS of html buttons element?

Tags: css, button, user-agent

I try to apply to buttons an elegant CSS style I found. I need to keep buttons for semantic/accessibility reasons. But my nice CSS is conflicting with the button elements' native CSS style, and loosing to it.

**How to override the natural CSS of html buttons' elements ?**

```
/* CSS works for buttonis, doesn't work for buttons*/
button.btn, buttoni.btn {  
   ... 
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bkWNw/3/

**Edit:** The buttons element should look exactly like the buttonis elements.

Comment: As per the answers below, your CSS isn't "conflicting" it's that the existing button style has a border specified and your style does not specify a border so the existing border is still present.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Either use a [CSS Reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/), or set the border and outline to `none`.

```
border: none;
outline: none;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bkWNw/5/

Answer (score 3):

### Here's a complete CSS reset:

#### In CSS

```css
.reset-style {
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  font: inherit;
  color: inherit;
  background-color: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
  }
```

```html
<button class="reset-style">This is clickable</button>
```

#### In JS:

```js
export const resetButton = {
    padding: 0,
    border: 'none',
    font: 'inherit',
    color: 'inherit',
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    cursor: 'pointer'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

On the latest browser you can also use `-webkit-appearance: none` `-moz-appearance: none` to remove the default styling from those elements. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/faueK/

Answer (score 1):

Just set `border: none` to get rid of that border.